# Laravel custom pagination on page 2 return as object

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

Laravel custom pagination page 2 result return as object not array.

**This is my code of custom pagination**

```
function custom_paginate($data)
{
    //Get current page form url e.g. &page=6
    $currentPage = LengthAwarePaginator::resolveCurrentPage();

    //Create a new Laravel collection from the array data
    $collection = new Collection($data);

    //Define how many items we want to be visible in each page
    $per_page = (int) per_page();

    //Slice the collection to get the items to display in current page
    $currentPageResults = $collection->slice(($currentPage - 1) * $per_page, $per_page)->all();

    //Create our paginator and add it to the data array
    $data['results'] = new LengthAwarePaginator($currentPageResults, count($collection), $per_page);

    //Set base url for pagination links to follow e.g custom/url?page=6
    return $data['results']->setPath(request()->url());
}
```

when i am at page 1 data is coming as array but in same code if i passed `page=2`result is coming as object.

**Expected result**

```
{
"current_page": 2,
"data": [
    {
        "_id": 34,
        "state": "Andaman & Nicobar Islands",
        "post_count": 8,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 1,
        "totalAudios": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": 28,
        "state": "Andhra Pradesh",
        "post_count": 888,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 111,
        "totalAudios": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": 12,
        "state": "Arunachal Pradesh",
        "post_count": 200,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 25,
        "totalAudios": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": 18,
        "state": "Assam",
        "post_count": 464,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 58,
        "totalAudios": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": 10,
        "state": "Bihar",
        "post_count": 1072,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 134,
        "totalAudios": 0
    }
],
"first_page_url": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts?page=1",
"from": 6,
"last_page": 8,
"last_page_url": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts?page=8",
"next_page_url": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts?page=3",
"path": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts",
"per_page": 5,
"prev_page_url": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts?page=1",
"to": 10,
"total": 36
```

}

but getting data as object on page 2 (**Actual result**)

```
{
"current_page": 2,
"data": {
    "5": {
        "_id": 4,
        "state": "Chandigarh",
        "post_count": 8,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 1,
        "totalAudios": 0
    },
    "6": {
        "_id": 22,
        "state": "Chhattisgarh",
        "post_count": 1336,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 167,
        "totalAudios": 0
    },
    "7": {
        "_id": 26,
        "state": "Dadra & Nagar Haveli",
        "post_count": 8,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 1,
        "totalAudios": 0
    },
    "8": {
        "_id": 25,
        "state": "Daman & Diu",
        "post_count": 16,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 2,
        "totalAudios": 0
    },
    "9": {
        "_id": 7,
        "state": "Delhi",
        "post_count": 40,
        "totalPhotos": 0,
        "totalVideos": 5,
        "totalAudios": 0
    }
},
"first_page_url": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts?page=1",
"from": 6,
"last_page": 8,
"last_page_url": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts?page=8",
"next_page_url": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts?page=3",
"path": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts",
"per_page": 5,
"prev_page_url": "http://swachh-manch-data.git/insight/posts?page=1",
"to": 10,
"total": 36
}
```

i am not sure but the problem is in `$currentPageResults = $collection->slice(($currentPage - 1) * $per_page, $per_page)->all();` this line.

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: try $currentPageResults = $collection->slice(($currentPage - 1) * $per_page, $per_page)->values();

Comment: @RossWilson okay

Comment: @PraffulPanwar please see my answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change

```
$currentPageResults = $collection->slice(($currentPage - 1) * $per_page, $per_page)->all();
```

to

```
$currentPageResults = $collection->slice(($currentPage - 1) * $per_page, $per_page)->values();
```

Due to the nature of how you are slicing the original collection, the array keys on page 2+ do not start at 0 and are subsequently considered to be associative keys of an object, which is why the outputted data is formatted as such.

To fix this, simply change the `all` method to `values` which will ensure that each item in the outputted page is numerically indexed from 0, and represented as an array.

For more info read [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-values).